# How to get a part of a webpage in MQL4?

Tags: c#, data-processing, mql4

I am new to programming. I need to program a code that will GET a webpage in MQL4 language. I copy/pasted a **`WebRequest()`** code:

```
res = WebRequest( "GET",
                  Inv_url,
                  cookie,
                  NULL,
                  timeout,
                  post,
                  0,
                  result,
                  headers
                  );
```

which **can download the whole page**.

**However** I would like to get just one table of the page, like when I create new query in Excel.

[Excel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp0k6.jpg)[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Zdravim do Brna :o)  -- jak moc vazny to je "projekt"?

Answer (score -1):

### Well, honestly, not a typical task for MQL4

**`MQL4`** started it's life as a language for an **ultra-fast / near-real-time** oriented code-execution platform ( a.k.a. [ MetaTrader Terminal 4 ] ).

This said, the language can handle very smart & fast register shifting, not to lose any amount of time inside the Market-event triggered data-stream-processing, cadence of which is many events inside a single millisecond, yes, **many inside a single millisecond** ( sometimes high number of hundreds of 'em in prime time ).

With this in focus, it comes natural, that there is literally **no direct language / syntax support** for any common markup-language-wrapped-`{http|script}`-composition and/or interaction with that.

For the first decade of it's life-cycle, **the originally solid `MQL4` language** ( not the recent year or two  <sub>( still a lot creeping )</sub>  ***New-*`MQL4.56789`** derivative attempt to move and enforce the `MQL4`-domain towards the `MQL5`-domain, but it is another topic, sure ), had no support for any kind of interactions "outside of the MT4-box". Simply nothing, to avoid any sort of disturbances from external non-core, potentially blocking processes, that could de-stabilise the tough real-time execution loop of the platform.

---

### That does not mean, one cannot extend MQL4 today to work with this

As a fast proxy solution, one may forget about `MQL4`-syntax ( functions et al ) and start thinking about doing the `MQL4`-part as usual and extend the [ MetaTrader Terminal 4 ] processes so as to become able to communicate with external ( distributed ) hosts, where ( as the easiest prototyping example ) a **`python`** process can do the job, that would otherwise be hard for `MQL4`.

This is exactly the **approach, where one does not risk `MQL4` troubles with parsing** the markup-language-wrapped-`{http|script}`-composition to find any element(s) one needs.

This builds on **`python`** strengths in doing this very part and leaves one in just orchestrating the mutual-cooperation of such distributed-process workflow.

---

### How to integrate the distributed-process workflows?

After many hundred man*years of experimenting and code-base maintenance, my choice No.1 is **`[ZeroMQ]`** or **`[nanomsg]`**.

When not willing to invest one's own "blood, tears & sweat" into these or other smart distributed signalling / communications architectures, one may use as a [last resort going into **`MQL4 WebRequest()`** even for integration against python-based lightweight-webServer to complete the intended processing-flow and deliver the wanted results onto MQL4-side.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39966404/3666197)